# How to manually run digest in an Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, components

I'm trying to write a controller like this:

```js
export default class someServiceCtrl{

    constructor(someService) {
        this.someService= someService;
        this.$isEditable = false;
        this.options = {};
        this.items=[];
        this.emptyData = true;
    }

    switchIsEditable(){
        this.$isEditable = !this.$isEditable;
        if(this.$isEditable){
            angular.element(document).on('keydown', function (e){
                if(e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 31){
                    this.$isEditable = false;
                }
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }

    dialogGotBlurred(){
        this.$isEditable = false;
    }
}

someServiceCtrl.$inject = ['someService'];
```

But the $isEditable never changes. 
I'm stuck at this point.

How to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I've been able to get this to work is to inject `$rootScope` and call `$rootScope.$digest()`. Not the most elegant solution, but it should allow you to do what you want.